Apply conditional formatting when the value in a row increases or decreases
I am trying to apply conditional formatting to a range of data, but not able to find a solution for it.
I am trying to do two types of formatting.

When a value in a row is less than the value in the previous column, I want the cell highlighted in red. For example, in the image below, cell T2 should be highlighted in red because T2<S2.


When a value in a row is greater than the value in the previous column, I want the cell to be highlighted in green. For example, in the image below, Q4 should be highlighted in green because Q4>P4.



The values are only compared to the previous column in the same row, but I want to apply the conditional formatting rule to all the rows in the table.
Link to example spreadsheet with the desired result

Basic Approach

Apply to Range: C2:U1000
Custom Formula: =C2>B2  or =C2<B2



Thanks so much!!! the solution worked for me!! :) :) Also thanks for helping to edit the question. Now it sounds less confusing. Sorry that i wasnt clear earlier. :)
